# Add new files to upload queue in real time

Tags: c#, file-upload, filesystemwatcher

What i want to do is to add new files to upload list **while** older files are being uploaded.

This is the code for uploading and the Watcher:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //get files from local path
            List<string> localFilesWithFullPath = 
            Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\myfiles").ToList();

            foreach (var file in localFilesWithFullPath)
            {
                // upload each file
                ftpClient.Upload("/" + Path.GetFileName(file), file);
            }
            Run(ftpClient, localFilesWithFullPath);
        }

        public static void Run(Ftp ftpClient, List<string> 
        localFilesWithFullPath)
        {
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher { Path = @"c:\myfiles" };
            watcher.Created += (source, e) =>
            {
                ftpClient.Upload("/" + e.Name, e.FullPath);
            };
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Console.Read();
        }
```

This is the [FtpClass](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class) for uploading, and it works perfect.

The problem with this code is it will add new files after the older files are uploaded completely **NOT** while they are uploading, so it will not add new files to queue in middle of uploading.

Q: How can i use Watcher (or something else) to add files to upload queue in real time ?

Comment: It is because of the reason that your code runs in a single thread, you need to create 2 threads one for uploading and other for adding files to queue for uploading

Comment: @IpsitGaur Yeah thanks. Created a 2nd thread and now it add to list in real time. But the problem is **adding item to list while iterating** that i am searching for it.